# Writing media queries and I don't understand why it will change my img width but not height?

Tags: css

This does not work:

```
@media (max-width : 600px) {
  img.resize {
    height : 10px;
  }
}
```

This does:

```
@media (max-width : 600px) {
  img.resize {
    width : 10px;
  }
}
```

Why? Do I need to add a min or max height? What's the deal with this?

Comment: Is the width set somewhere else that might be interfering with the height property? I.e. do you need to also add `width: auto`?

Comment: @webdevkit the height is set elsewhere at 300px while the width of the images are set to different percentages. do I need to try and use a percentage for the height?

Comment: Hmm. Might need to create a fiddle or something to really show the issue. My instinct is that the properties are interfering with each other. Perhaps your other heights are being set with a selector that has more specificity, which is overriding the @media declaration. Hard to tell without inspecting the CSS of the image in question using a browser's Dev Tools.

Comment: const fiftyFifty = {
      width: '50%',
      marginTop: "0px",
      height: "300px",



    }

    const fifteen = {
      width: '15%',
      marginTop: "100px",
      height: "300px"
    }
    const fifty = {
      width: '50%',
      marginTop: "0px",
      height: "300px"
    }
    const twentyFive = {
      width: '25%',
      marginTop: "0px",
      height: "300px"
    }

    const seventy = {
      marginTop: "100px",
      width: '70%',
      height: "300px"
    } I'm in react, this is the css previously written for it.. I don't know what I'm doing obvs

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because something else is overwriting it. Try with !important to see if it changes, if it does then something else is overwriting it. `height: 10px !important;`. Btw you should not use important if you can avoid